# Unity - MRTK 2.7.3 Holographic Remoting App - Sounds are coming from pc speaker

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I'm trying to add some audio clips to my Holographic Remoting App. However, when I execute the app sounds come from pc speaker. I want to use the speaker of Hololens 2 for the audio clips. I have searched on the internet but I couldn't find any solution. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are previewing your project through **Holographic Remoting For Play Mode** in Unity Editor. Then you only need to check **Enable Audio** in **Holographic Remoting For Play Mode** to hear the audio clip on the HoloLens 2 device.

Note that after checking **Enable Audio**, the audio clip will be played on the PC and HoloLens 2 together.

Comment: Actually, I am testing the app after I get build.

Comment: I have tried to check Enable Audio but it didn't work. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Hello again. The cause of the problem was that the application did not see my sound card driver. I updated the driver and checked enable audio. It is working now. Thanks a lot.